# Find path from a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples of the form:

```
data = [('Abe', 'Bob', '3'), 
        ('Abe', 'Frank', '5'),
        ('Abe', 'George', '4'),
        ('Carl', 'Bob', '1'),
        ('Dan', 'Carl', '2')]
```

This data simulates an undirected graph, where there is a connection from 'Abe' to 'Bob' of size 3. Because the graph is undirected, it also means that there is a connection from 'Bob' to 'Abe' of size 3 as well.

I need to show whether or not there is a connection between two inputs and what its weight is. For example, if the input was 'Abe', 'Dan', the result would return the shortest (least node hops, NOT least weight) path from 'Abe' to 'Dan' which would be Abe, Bob, Carl, Dan and the weight, 3+1+2 = 6.

I have this code which shows whether or not 'Abe' would reach 'Dan', but I don't know how to return the path.

```
def get_path_and_weight(data, start, end):

    reachable = [start]
    added = -1

    while added != 0:
        added = 0
        for first, second, weight in data:
            if(first in reachable) and (second not in reachable):
                reachable.append(second)
                added += 1
            if(first not in reachable) and (second in reachable): 
                reachable.append(first)
                added += 1

        if (end in reachable):
            print("YES")
            #return path
        else:
            print("NO")
```

Comment: Are you sure the algorithm itself is correct? Maybe the reason you cannot figure out the path is that you don't actually check it. Check it for a graph that is disconnected. At a glance you just answer whether a vertex is in graph. What you want to do is breadth-first-search or deep-first-search.

Comment: I've not had my coffee yet but my first idea is to just do Dijkstra with a pseudo-weight of 1 for every edge, this will give you the path with the least amount of hops from one node to another. Then add the actual weights of the edges used later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate all the possible paths, and sort them by weight.  Note I've changed the weights in the data to be numbers, not strings:

```
data = [
    ('Abe', 'Bob', 3), 
    ('Abe', 'Frank', 5),
    ('Abe', 'George', 4),
    ('Carl', 'Bob', 1),
    ('Dan', 'Carl', 2),
]

WEIGHT = 0
NODES = slice(1, None)

def get_path_and_weight(data, start, end):

    paths = [[0, start]]
    added = True

    while added:
        added = False

        for first, second, weight in data:
            for path in paths:
                candidate = None

                if (first in path[NODES]) and (second not in path[NODES]):
                    candidate = second
                elif (first not in path[NODES]) and (second in path[NODES]):
                    candidate = first

                if candidate:
                    new_path = list(path)
                    new_path.append(candidate)
                    new_path[WEIGHT] += weight

                    if new_path not in paths:
                        paths.append(new_path)
                        added = True

    for path in sorted(paths):
        if end in path[NODES]:
            return path

    return None
```

You can then call this something like:

```
weight, *path = get_path_and_weight(data, "Abe", "Dan")

print(path, "with weight", weight)
```

Gives the result:

```
['Abe', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'Dan'] with weight 6
```

And since it returns a path or `None`, you can still use it as predicate function as well:

```
if get_path_and_weight(data, "Abe", "Dan"):
    print("connected")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages that are already developed and debugged that do this, e.g., [`networkx`](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/networkx-1.11/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path)

```
import networkx as nx

data = [('Abe', 'Bob', '3'), 
        ('Abe', 'Frank', '5'),
        ('Abe', 'George', '4'),
        ('Carl', 'Bob', '1'),
        ('Dan', 'Carl', '2')]

g = nx.Graph()
for e in data:
    g.add_edge(e[0], e[1], distance=int(e[2]))
>>> nx.shortest_path(g, 'Abe', 'Bob', 'distance'), nx.shortest_path_length(g, 'Abe', 'Bob', 'distance')
(['Abe', 'Bob'], 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_rpath_with_weight(data,start,end):
    rpath = []
    reachable=False
    nxt_dst = start
    weight_ = 0
    rpath.append(nxt_dst)
    for datum in data:
        if nxt_dst in datum:
            #print datum
            fm_ = datum[0]
            to_ = datum[1]
            weight_ = weight_ + int(datum[2])
            if fm_ == nxt_dst:
               nxt_dst = to_
            else:
               nxt_dst = fm_
            if nxt_dst == end:
               reachable=True
            rpath.append(nxt_dst)
    print rpath,weight_,reachable


get_rpath_with_weight(data,'Abe','Dan')

get_rpath_with_weight(data,'Dan','Frank')
```

Sample Output

```
['Abe', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'Dan'] 6 True
['Dan', 'Carl'] 2 False
```

Above example can may get path and determine if reachable, but I think you need to further enhance it to handle multiple paths too.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in this, if you reverse the start and end, `get_rpath_with_weight(data,'Dan','Abe')` you should get the same basic result, just path reversed, but instead you get: `['Dan', 'Carl'] 2 False`

Comment: Yeah, since the example is just want to inspire and not a give and take answer, reverse path and multiple path didn't handle. Maybe later. :)